# Altium: PCB filter GUI

Tags: altium

The PCB filter GUI menu looks like this:

[image]

What is not clear is how this is supposed to be used. There are two set of items, vertical and horizontal. From the vertical items on the left, I can understand some of them like Polygon, Text, Track, Via, Pad e.t.c. From the horizontal items on the top I can understand what Net and Component mean by not sure about Free.

What exactly does it mean when we click on one of the boxes? Lets take some example Track-Net, Track-Component, Track-Free. What does it really mean to check these boxes? Now lets take another example. Pad-Net, Via-Component and Arc-Free. What would it mean if the boxes were checked corresponding to this?

I know that checking the boxes generates scripting commands into a box further down. However, so far, it is not clear how this PCB filter is really supposed to be used.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-the-query-language?version=23&help-data=PCB.Dlg.PCB%20Filter.ScrollBox.SimpleFilterGridFrame.TreeList_Objects#!pcb_filter_panel) on this specific feature?

Answer (score 2):

The PCB Filter panel is a way to select objects by queries and includes a couple of tools to help build those queries. (One tool being the Builder button and another being the matrix selections you see in the panel.)

The [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-the-query-language?version=23&help-data=PCB.Dlg.PCB%20Filter.ScrollBox.SimpleFilterGridFrame.TreeList_Objects#!pcb_filter_panel) doesn't explain very clearly what the object categories **Net**, **Component**, and **Free** are:

> The main region of the panel provides controls for quickly building simple filter expressions targeting any combination of objects. Object types are arranged in an 'object matrix', categorized in accordance with being net objects (Net), component objects (Comp), or free objects (Free).

But it's actually not complicated at all:

- **Net**: This category effectively means "objects that are assigned to a net." If, for example, you enable this category and click *Apply To All*, objects that match the object type (*tracks* per your example) that are assigned to some net (like "GND" or "R13_1", etc.) will be selected.
- **Component**: This category means "objects that are part of a component." Imagine that a component includes some tracks in its footprint — a common example of this might be some lines or a rectangle drawn on the silkscreen layer to indicate component placement. These are considered tracks. Since they are members of a component object type, they would be selected when using this selection filter.
- **Free**: Free objects are the "everything else" category. Again, referring to your example, if you draw a track somewhere on your PCB and don't assign a net to it, it is "free." This applies to lines drawn on non-copper layers as well, such as silkscreen, mechanical, or drill guide layers.

The matrix selection checkboxes are additive, so if you enable "Pad-Net," "Via-Component," and "Arc-Free" you would be selecting all of the following:

- Pads that have been assigned a net (regardless of free/component membership)
- Vias that are part of a component footprint (regardless of net assignment)
- Arcs that are not assigned a net and are not part of a component

The resulting filter query can be further modified by directly editing it; for example, you might have a case where you need to quickly select all pads that are not assigned any net, but you're aware of a few that are *meant* to be that way. You might create a query that selects all "free pads" but modify the query to exclude the ones you don't care about. The query could then be saved as a favorite for reuse.

For example, say you just want to check for unassigned pads, but for whatever reason you want R2 pads to be left out of the selection. (This example is pretty silly, because this sort of check is normally handled by design rules, but hopefully it makes the point.)

`IsPad And IsFree And Not InComponent('R2')`

I primarily use the PCB Filter panel in a sort of reporting fashion when I need to share with colleagues the arrangement of fencing vias, or a series of connectors, or tracks and polygons that are meant for a particular purpose such as power distribution. Using this panel allows you to select things that are of interest, and through the use of masks/highlighting result in a visual that shows the objects of interest very clearly against the noise of an otherwise complicated PCB.